# Parts of Speech Tagging in JAVA NLP

Tags: java, nlp, tagging

First of, I am not asking for codes. I will be just asking for suggestions or ideas on how to start this project so please help me I want to learn.

INPUT TEXT FILE:
Five little monkeys jumping on the bed
One fell off and bumped his head
Mama called the doctor and the doctor said:
"No more monkeys jumping on the bed!"

**OUTPUT:**

Noun:
Monkeys
Doctor

(and other parts of speech)

If i remove one word from the text file it will also be gone from the Output. Is this program possible without downloading anything like the Stanford? I'm using Java. I don't know how to start it without ideas :(

Question:
What method am I going to use.

**EDIT!!!!!!!!!!!**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Users/xxxx/Desktop/lyrics.txt"));
         String line = null;
         while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 

         {
             System.out.println("Noun: ");

         }
    }

    }
```

HERE NOW IT ALREADY READS MY TEXTFILE. I thought of an idea that i can just find a specific word in the text file and print it out as, "Noun: Monkeys" but without the user input. What i'm talking about is something like this one

Type word to find: ExampleWord

Output:

Sys.out.print( word + "Found!");

Can do something like this without asking for the user? It will just automatically print out every word?